# Unable to recreate a sharepoint site with a name that was previously used

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, site, enterprise-search

I created a test site in sharepoint using the Enterprise search template with the name 'search'.  So my site was `http://mysite/search`.  Well I deleted that site and tried to recreate it with that same name and it fails.

I can create a site with the name search1, search2, etc and they all are created properly, but if I delete search1, or search2 and repeat what I did above those fails as well.

It seems like sharepoint isn't properly deleting the sites and there are orphaned files somewhere.

Any suggestions as to how I can resolve this?

Comment: How long has it been since you deleted them?  Maybe it has to crawl to see that the names are no longer being used?

Comment: Weeks... but the amount of times between the deletions don't seem to have an affect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like, Site is still in SharePoint Admin Bin.You should this.

- Use powershell to create site collection

Or

- Run this command Get-SPDeletedSite[enter link description here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316(v=office.15).aspx) and if you get all the sites you are having issue then
- Run [Remove-SPDeletedSite -Identity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286317(v=office.15).aspx)
- Manually run the **Gradual Site Delete** timer job from central admin.
- after this try to created again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the this command

```
Get-SPWebApplication <http://url:port> | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, URL, ID, ParentWebID
```

This will return the id and parent id for all sub sites from the choosed site.
If your "search" site is on this list, you could use:

```
Remove-SPWeb <http://url>
```